# AWS CloudFormation multi-region feature

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have two availability zones in US west and three availability zones in US east, how to update below cloud formation template to choose three subnets for east and two for east region

```
  "Properties" : {
  "VPCZoneIdentifier" : [
    { "Ref" : "PrivateSubnet1" },
    { "Ref" : "PrivateSubnet2" }
 ],
```

Comment: What resource are you trying to define? Auto-Scaling Group? VPC?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to automatically insert a list of all Availability Zones in the region:

```
"AvailabilityZones" : { "Fn::GetAZs" : "" }
```